# OpenFL - How to use addChild in another class?

Tags: haxe, addchild, openfl

The answer should be simple but I can't find out how anywhere..

So I have a Main.hx class and a ObjectManager.hx class. 
In the main class's constructor, it calls ObjectManager.addAllToScreen(); and my objectManager should then add the objects to the screen.

I thought this would be ok because in the constructor of Main you can just say addChild(Objects.platform); but apparently addChild isn't accessible?

The error is: `Class<Main> has no field addChild` so I'd guess that addChild is a method of Sprite or something?

```
package;

class Main extends Sprite {
    public function new() {
        super();
        ObjectManager.addAllToScreen();
    }
}
```

In ObjectManager:

```
package;

class ObjectManager {
    public static function addAllToScreen():Void {
        Main.addChild(Objects.platform);
        Main.addChild(Objects.messageField);
    }
}
```

UPDATE:

Ok so now the code is this... and it runs just fine apart from the objects never showing up on screen - however if the addChild code is put in main, they do show up.

Main:

```
class Main extends Sprite {

public function new() {
    super();
    var objectManager = new ObjectManager();
    objectManager.addAllToScreen();
}
```

ObjectManager:

```
package;
import openfl.display.Sprite;    

class ObjectManager extends Sprite {
    public function new() {
        super();
    }
    public function addAllToScreen() {
        addChild(Objects.platform);
        addChild(Objects.messageField);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

addChild() is available in `openfl.DisplayObjectContainer`, which `Sprite` extends. So you would need to make your class extend Sprite, yes.

Comment: Hi, I've updated the code to what I think you say it should be changed to but it's now giving me a new error...

Comment: You're using a static function. addChild() has to be called from an instance.

Comment: Ok I think we're getting there - it's no longer a static call and throws no errors but still no objects show.

Comment: You need to addChild() the objects to the instance of Main(). It'd be a bit of a hack, but you could create a static variable in Main, call it "instance" or whatever, and then set it to "this" in Main's new() function. Then you can do Main.instance.addChild() and stuff will be attached to your document class.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to pass a reference to the stage to your ObjectManager class so you can add things to it later on.

Check this out.

Main.hx

```
package;

import openfl.display.Sprite;

class Main extends Sprite {
    public function new () {
        super();

        ObjectManager.setup(stage);
        ObjectManager.addAllToScreen();
    }
}
```

ObjectManager.hx

```
package ;

import openfl.display.Sprite;
import openfl.display.Stage;

class ObjectManager {

    // The reference to the applications stage
    private static var stage:Stage;

    // Do this first,
    // we need to hold a reference to the Stage object so we can add to it later
    public static function setup(stageref:Stage) {
        stage = stageref;
    }

    public static function addAllToScreen() {
        // An array of randomly generated sprite objects
        var sprites:Array<Sprite> = [randomSprite(), randomSprite(), randomSprite()];

        for(sprite in sprites) {
            // Position the sprites randomly over the screen
            sprite.x = Math.random() * stage.stageWidth;
            sprite.y = Math.random() * stage.stageHeight;

            // Add them to the stage
            stage.addChild(sprite);
        }
    }

    // Ignore this
    // Makes a randomly sized circle in a random colour
    private static function randomSprite():Sprite {
        var spr = new Sprite();

        spr.graphics.beginFill(Std.int(0xffffff * Math.random()), 1);
        spr.graphics.drawCircle(0, 0, (Math.random() * 100) + 20);
        spr.graphics.endFill();

        return spr;
    }
}
```